Why is a C=C weaker than a C=N and even weaker than a C=O when C-C is stronger than C-N and C-O?
Why is a C=C bond weaker than a C=N and even weaker than C=O ? In terms of orbital overlap it doesn't make sense, since there is a difference in energy between the orbitals which lower the interaction strength(As can be seen in the trend for single bonds C-C, C-N, C-O.

Can it be because N and O are more electronegative, and since they are also closer to a full shell, electrons in the bond spend more time around the electronegative atom and that makes the whole system lower in energy, like an ionic character a ''partial electron transfer'' and electrons around more electronegative elements are generally lower in energy because of the stronger interaction with the nucleus?

